# Problem with designing class

Tags: java, enums

I have a classes as below

```
public class Book extends Item{ ...}
public class DVD extends Item{ ...}
```

Book can be of type REFRENCE or ISSUE.
DVD can be of type  ISSUE only.

So should I create Item as follows?

```
public class Item {

  public enum ItemType{REFRENCE,ISSUE};
  ItemType itemtype;

}
```

Or I should declare seperate enum for both book and DVD?

Answer (score 4):

How about defining two interfaces `Reference` and `Issue` and `Book` will implement both while `DVD` will implement only `Issue`?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Is a DVD ISSUE the same as a book ISSUE?

If so then put it in the parent class and throw an exception if you create a REFERENCE DVD.

If it isnt then define seperate public enums in the two subclasses.

Comment: both issue are same.Which approach will be better?And can i throw a exception in a constrructor?i guess no

Comment: Then declare the enum in the base class. Otherwise you could have an ISSUE DVD and an ISSUE book where book.getType() and dvd.getType arent comparable, being distinct types.

Comment: Oh, and yes, you can throw an exception from a contructor - probably IllegalArgumentException in this case.

Comment: so which approach is better ?

Comment: both types are comparable as types just indicates if the book/item can be taken home or just can be hsued for regrence in library

Comment: No, they wont be comparable. If you have distinct enums then DVD.Type.ISSUE == Book.Type.ISSUE wont compile, as theyre different types.

Answer (score 1):

By storing something's type in an enum you are going against using the object oriented features of the language. 
Also, I don't feel that an "item" "has a" property of being an issue/reference. It's more of an "is a" relation, which suggests you should use inheritence/interfaces.
Of course the right approach depends on what your program is meant to do. Sometimes object oriented constructs can get in your way.